# How to override get_avatar() function?

Tags: hooks, avatar, pluggable

I need for a specific plugin to override the wordpress function `get_avatar()` to bind the profile image to an other image with some condition.

How can I do this ?
Is there a specific hook or filter to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is get_avatar filter. [codex ref](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/get_avatar)

Answer (score 0):

I can ovveride in `functions.php` the function `get_avatar()` but the best way seems to use the filter `get_avatar`.

I found the answer here :
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/get_avatar

Answer (score 0):

The avatar function has a filter hook [`get_avatar`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_avatar/). You should use this to filter and replace with your function, like the following example, without logic.

```
add_filter( 'get_avatar', 'get_avatar', 10, 5 );
/**
 *  Override get_avatar with uploaded avatar else default.
 */
function get_avatar( $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt )
{   
    $avatar = "<img alt='{$alt}' src='{$avatar_path}' class='avatar avatar-{$size} photo avatar-default' height='{$size}' width='{$size}' />";
    return $avatar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_avatar/)

You can use the following filter -

```php
// Apply filter
add_filter( 'get_avatar' , 'my_avatar_func' , 1 , 5 );
 
function my_avatar_func( $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt ) {
// your code here 
}
```

Comment: That's pretty much the same as all the other answers, isn't it? What's new here?